# webview goBack() does not work properly

Tags: android, webview

My application loads an URL of a website into an Android WebView. This website has multiple pages.

If I then press the back button, `webView.canGoBack()` gets called.

If `webView.canGoBack()` returns false, then the app exits.
But if it returns true, it calls the `webView.goBack()`, but that doesn't trigger any action.

Following is the code snippet that is used in `onBackPressed()`.

```
if (mWvContent.isFocused() && mWvContent.canGoBack()) {
    mWvContent.goBack()
} else {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

Extra info: I am using a `WebViewClient`, overriding "`shouldOverrideUrlLoading`" and enabling javascript:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Any ideas?

Edit :-

```
private boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final String url) {
     Log.i("", "shouldOverrideUrlLoading() URL : " + url);

     mWvContent.loadUrl(url);

     return false; // Returning True means that application wants to 
            leave the current WebView and handle the url itself, otherwise 
            return false.
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help, if you shared your `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` code.

But in any case that is most likely, where the problem lies. You should return false for that method when you want it to behave normally. If you are returning true then even when you say `webView.goBack()`, it will do nothing expecting you to handle it yourself.

Additionally depending on the page you are loading, you may be experiencing an infinite redirect loop.

Edit: With the update to your answer I can see the problem. You are calling:

```
 mWvContent.loadUrl(url);
```

This is what is happening:

webView.goBack() is called, then you loadUrl(url), then you return false telling webView to handle everything for you, so it goes back.

End Result is you end up in the same spot.

Solution: Remove  mWvContent.loadUrl(url);

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I edited my post. Kindly check it now. I've return false in the shouldOverrideUrlLoading methos.

Comment: See my edit. you shouldn't call loadUrl unless you are doing something special to the url. False means you are letting the system handle everything so calling loadUrl does it twice.